# I don't understand what is the purpose of .text in spacy code

Tags: nlp, spacy

I have the following code:

```
    from spacy.lang.en import English

    nlp = English()

    # Process the text
    doc = nlp("I like tree kangaroos and narwhals.")

    # Select the first token
    first_token = doc[0]

    # Print the first token's text
    print(first_token**.text**)
```

The problem with .text in the end of the code is that even if I omit it everything works fine.
I have seen the .text method many times in spacy coding but I don't understand what is it doing.
My question is simple what is this .text method doing?

Comment: *"`print(first_token)` works fine"* != *"everything works fine"*. Other commands will break. The only reason `print()` doesn't also break is it calls `__str__` under the hood on each object, (and  if `__str__` doesn't exist on an object, it calls `__repr__`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `doc[0]` is a [Token](https://spacy.io/api/token), not a string.

Using `.text` is returning the string that your `Token` object holds. The `Token` can have plenty of other attributes, too.

When `Token` objects are printed, the representation is just the text!—see [the source code](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/master/spacy/tokens/token.pyx#L112). That's why they look the same when you print `first_token` and `first_token.text`.

*Power user stuff; skip if you want:* If you want to see why the behavior is different between `Token` and string objects, try concatenating two `Token`s with `+`, or comparing them for equality. They don't have `__eq__` implemented, so the comparison is just based on the `Token`'s address in memory.